# Ultimate tic tac toe detection of tiles next to eachother in Java

Tags: java, bots, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to make an AI/bot in UTTT, my issue here is im trying to detect when there is two tiles placed from the same side next to each other. I have a method for detecting when there is 3, but i cannot for the life of me change it so it only detects 2.

```
 public static boolean isWin(String[][] board, IMove move, String currentPlayer){
    int localX = move.getX() % 3;
    int localY = move.getY() % 3;
    int startX = move.getX() - (localX);
    int startY = move.getY() - (localY);

    //check col
    for (int i = startY; i < startY + 3; i++) {
        if (!board[move.getX()][i].equals(currentPlayer))
            break;
        if (i == startY + 3 - 1) return true;
    }

    //check row
    for (int i = startX; i < startX + 3; i++) {
        if (!board[i][move.getY()].equals(currentPlayer))
            break;
        if (i == startX + 3 - 1) return true;
    }

    //check diagonal
    if (localX == localY) {
        //we're on a diagonal
        int y = startY;
        for (int i = startX; i < startX + 3; i++) {
            if (!board[i][y++].equals(currentPlayer))
                break;
            if (i == startX + 3 - 1) return true;
        }
    }

    //check anti diagonal
    if (localX + localY == 3 - 1) {
        int less = 0;
        for (int i = startX; i < startX + 3; i++) {
            if (!board[i][(startY + 2)-less++].equals(currentPlayer))
                break;
            if (i == startX + 3 - 1) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is what i have for detecting whether or not there is a winner (3 in a row).

Comment: It's been a day and nobody answered, so you might want to try clarifying your question, what exactly you have trouble with/why what you already tried didn't work and also try to better explain what your current code here currently does.